# Upgrading site to HTML5; is Yahoo site verification important at all?

Tags: seo, yahoo, w3c-validation, meta-tags, yahoo-api

I'm working on redesigning an older site and I'm upgrading it to HTML5. The site currently has **both** Google and Yahoo site verification META tags.

I'm using [HTML5 Reset](http://html5reset.org/) as a starting template and it only has an area for Google site verification, not Yahoo. Also, the W3C Validator validates Google site verification in HTML5, but not Yahoo.

Does anyone have an opinion as to whether or not Yahoo site verification is important or useful? And does it hold any weight with SEO these days?

Comment: what is Google site verification META tags? please elaborate.

Comment: Google Site Verification: <meta name="google-site-verification" content="######"> The ### being the custom site verification number for the website. Yahoo's site verification follows this same format but the name="" will not validate.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Yahoo search is now [powered by Bing](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/search/archive/2010/08/24/exciting-news-from-bing-and-yahoo.aspx).

You can remove both (Google and Bing) verification references and authenticate using other methods ([DNS is best](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/dns-verification-ftw.html)). Bing only offers [meta tag and XML](http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/gg132924.aspx) methods.